# Add Content Editor webpart in masterpage with Target audience

Tags: 2013, master-page, content-editor-web-part, audience-targeting

I have my custom master page developed in SharePoint 2013, Now I have a requirement to have some links to be visible for only particular user/group (not on permission so `SecurityTrimmedControl` will not work for me).

So I have came up with thought to have `Content Editor` Webpart and put `Target Audience` in that webpart properties. But when I tried to add this webpart from the `Snippet Gallery` in masterpage, it has no `Target Audience` Property.

Can anyone tell me the other possible way except `JavaScript/Server side code` to check the logged in user permission and then show the link?

Comment: You can use Top Navigation/Left Navigation where you can set target audience for particular link. Is this is not an option for you?

Comment: Sorry but that's not an option for me. :) Just wanted to know if any other alternative is there except coding. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` to show/hide based on the permission.

Assuming that you need to show links to user who have edit permission, you can add the below snippet in the master page. Here in the permission string, i have set the value as EditListItems:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="EditListItems">
    <div id="secretContent">
    ...html
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path-to/custom.js"></script>
 </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Reference - [Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx)

For values in PermissionsString - [SPBasePermissions enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690)

This will render the above html content only to users who have the necessary permission.

Comment: Thank you for the your answer but this works on permission, I already tried this and I wanted to do it based on the group not on permission. Appreciate your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky solution:
You can add a webpart to a page normally, in a webpart zone.
In this **webpart** you can specify the css style to display or hide any element you want.
Finally set target audience to this **webpart** and everything will work as expected.